Registry value set default automatically when we move into another key of registry
We need to change value of Usbstor to 4 (to restrict usb ) but when I set it to 4 then after refresh registry /move another key & back to Usbstor again value set to 3 automatically,
In this case ho to restrict usb when value cannot set to 4
Please help
